# Deep inelastic scattering and the $Q^2 \rightarrow \infty$ limit.

Tags: quantum-field-theory, metric-tensor, quantum-chromodynamics, causality, scattering-cross-section

I am reading through Bailin and Love's argument (see P.151-152 of 'Introduction to Gauge Field Theory') that as $Q^2 \rightarrow \infty$, we probe the product of the two electromagnetic currents appearing in the hadronic tensor for DIS on the lightcone.  I will write out the argument here and point out my questions as I go along.

The Bjorken limit is defined as the limit in which $Q^2 \rightarrow \infty, p \cdot q \rightarrow \infty$ with Bjorken $x$ fixed.  As we will now show, the Bjorken limit corresponds to studying the light cone in coordinate space. To see this, it is convenient to work in the frame in which $p = (m_N, 0, 0, 0 )$ and $q = (q^0, 0, 0, q^0)$ with the z axis chosen along the direction of momentum of the virtual photon.

**($1$st question: This parametrisation of momenta does not allow for a virtual photon -  $q^2 = 0$ no? Perhaps there is a typo in his parametrisation because then the rest of the argument has no foundation I think)**

In lightcone variables, $q^2 = q_+ q_-$ and $p \cdot q = (m_N/2)(q_+ + q_-)$ and therefore $$x = \frac{-q_+ q_-}{m_N(q_+ + q_-)}$$The Bjorken limit is thus the limit $q_+ \rightarrow \infty$ with $q_-$ fixed (and negative). Consequently, $x = -q_-/m_N$.

(**$2$nd question: why the Bjorken limit corresponds to $q_+ \rightarrow \infty$? $x$ as written is symmetric in $q_+ \leftrightarrow q_-$ so singling out $q_+$ as the one that gets large seems incorrect, no?)**

Expanding the exponential appearing in the hadronic tensor in terms of lightcone components: $$e^{i qx} = \exp \left(\frac{i}{2} (q_+ x_- + q_- x_+) \right)$$ The exponential oscillates rapidly as $q^+ \rightarrow \infty$ so that the only contribution to the integral comes from the region $x_- = 0$.  Then $$x^2 = x_+ x_-  - \mathbf x^2 \leq 0 $$ The strict inequality can't hold because of causality therefore we must have $x^2 = 0$, as required.

(**$3$rd question: $x^2 < 0$ would have implied that the currents were spacelike separated - why is this a bad thing? Is it because they would be in different regions of the lightcone diagram and hence never 'talk' to each other? )**